# Rust narrow traits in function parameter

Tags: rust

I've got a situation in which I need a trait which *extends* another trait as a parameter in a function. I say *extends* because in TypeScript, this would be perfectly acceptable - an object may have more than the required list of properties.

My code looks like this: (For context, I'm attempting to implement a **very** simple UI toolkit)

```rust
pub trait Widget {
  // stuff related to widgets
}

 // All `MeasurableWidget`s are `Widget`s
pub trait MeasurableWidget: Widget {
  // allow the widget to be measured
}

pub struct ScrollBox {
  // stuff related to scrollboxes
}

pub trait Layout {
  fn insert_child(&mut self, child: Rc<dyn Widget>);
  // more stuff related to layouts
}
```

The issue is that a `ScrollBox` needs to know the dimensions of it's child, hence it's child needs to implement `MeasurableWidget`, rather than just `Widget`.

```rust
impl Layout for ScrollBox {
  // Rightfully won't compile because the types don't match
  fn insert_child(&mut self, child: Rc<dyn MeasurableWidget>) {
    // insert magic here
  }
}
```

Specifically, I'm getting Compiler-Error `E0053`:

```
error[E0053]: method `insert_child` has an incompatible type for trait
```

If this were TypeScript-land, this wouldn't be an issue. Since all `MeasurableWidget`s extend `Widget`, this is fine. However, naturally, `Widget` and `MeasurableWidget` are different sizes, so Rust can't know at compile-time which is which.

How would I enforce all calls to `ScrollBox::insert_child` to take an `Rc<dyn MeasurableWidget>` instead of allowing a plain ol' `Widget`, given that I need to know the dimensions of the child, and that some layouts don't require their child's dimensions?

Of course I have tried numerous variations of how the `MeasurableWidget` trait is defined and how the function works, but it's notoriously difficult to trick the Rust compiler into breaking certain rules. :P

Thanks

Jake

Comment: I think writing UI toolkits is one of those things where existing paradigms failed completely with Rust. A lot of rethinking had to happen, and it took quite a while until the first ones emerged. I think you will run into more problems if you continue with your project. Just warning you, though, don't let me stop you ;)

Comment: Actually I've noticed that a bit, was hoping I'd get away with it, but in truth, I haven't managed in any other language either, so I've got a few ideas that seem to be working so far, so I'm rolling with it until more issue like this arise, and I inevitably hit a bigger roadblock

Answer (score 2):

You could solve it with an associated type:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

pub trait Widget {
    // stuff related to widgets
}

// All `MeasurableWidget`s are `Widget`s
pub trait MeasurableWidget: Widget {
    // allow the widget to be measured
}

pub struct ScrollBox {
    // stuff related to scrollboxes
}

pub trait Layout {
    type ChildRef;
    fn insert_child(&mut self, child: Self::ChildRef);
    // more stuff related to layouts
}

impl Layout for ScrollBox {
    type ChildRef = Rc<dyn MeasurableWidget>;
    fn insert_child(&mut self, child: Self::ChildRef) {
        // insert magic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to make the restricted type be require _at least_ a widget?   Something like `trait Layout { type ChildRef: Widget; ...`?

Comment: What do you mean with *"at least"*? Rust is not an OOP language, there is no such thing as class hierarchies :)

Comment: Hence the question - I'm aware that Rust does not support inheritance in the way Java and the like do. My question related to how I would recreate such a behaviour

Comment: So I'm in the process of trying your answer, and I've noticed that I'm getting similar compiler errors about unknown size at compile time. Which unfortunately means it doesn't work :/

Comment: My question is still what you mean with *"at least"*, conceptually. I expect that you need it to fulfill a set of requirements to be usable for your struct. There is no *"at least"* there, either it fulfills those requirements or not. And those requirements should in some way be represented by traits. For example, if it's "measureable", it should implement a trait *"Measureable"*, as you already mention here. Which is arguably what my code does. So what else do you want it to do?

Comment: I used your answer to help me get close to my "solution" below, so yes, your answer is correct in that it describes how a `Measurable` _extends_ (is at least) a `Widget`. However, due to the unknown size of the widget at compile-time, I'm unable to fully accept your answer.

Comment: Feel free not to. I'd prefer if you actually show me what the problem is instead of saying pointless things that I can't help you with because you provide zero information about them.

Comment: Your sentence reads a little like "Technically your answer works for the question I asked, but for unspecified reasons I won't tell you it doesn't work in my specific usecase that I won't show you, so your answer is wrong" - I don't think this entirely reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, several hours of intense Rust sorcery has led to to a solution:

Instead of attempting to coerce `MeasurableWidget`s into `Widget`s, I instead make the type of the child a Generic parameter, I can specify which I need at the time of instantiation (OOP lingo to the rescue)

```rust
pub trait Layout<T: Widget> {
  fn insert_child(&mut self, child: Rc<T>)
  // more stuff
}
```

By doing this, I cause the compiler to inform me of unknown sizes at compile time:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn Widget + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
```

However, by removing the `Sized` trait from the type bound, the compiler seems to accept this.

```rust
pub trait Layout<T: Widget + ?Sized> {
  fn insert_child(&mut self, child: Rc<T>)
  // more stuff
}
```

Now, I will admit that I don't like this approach as there's clearly something *strange* happening, which I don't understand. If anyone can shed some light into what's going on in that example and why it works, please let me know.

I'd like to also mention that @Finomnis ' answer is getting close. But the same `+ ?Sized` issue arises. Thanks so much for your help regardless.

Comment: *"But the same `+ ?Sized` issue arises."* - How are you sure it's the same issue? There can be many reasons why this could happen, some of them easy to solve :)

Comment: Admittedly, I don't know it's the same issue, but given that the compiler mentions the same lack of statically-known size, it's a reasonable assumption

Comment: No it's not. Please actually post the code you are talking about instead of making assumptions.